# Why add method concatenate element of arrList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string which is an boolean equation : data1+data2.data3 .. I would like to put my string text in an arrayList `eq.getEquation()`

So, at the end I would like to have `[data1,+,data2,.,data3]`.

That is the purpose of my code. But the issue is when I add string to my `arrayList` *(using add method : `eq.getEquation().add())`. I don't know why but when I do : `eq.getEquation().add(str.toString());` my string is concatened with the previous element and not added it...

```
public void DmdViewToPasteTextFromClipboard(String text){
        if(text!=null){
            int item=0;
            String[] ArrOfStr = text.split("");
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i<ArrOfStr.length; i++){
                if(!ArrOfStr[i].equals("+") && !ArrOfStr[i].equals(".") && !ArrOfStr[i].equals("¤") &&
                        !ArrOfStr[i].equals("!")&&!ArrOfStr[i].equals("(")|| !ArrOfStr[i].equals(")")){
                    str.append(ArrOfStr[i]);                
                }else{
                    //System.out.print("str : "+ str +"\n");
//                  eq.getEquation().add(str.toString());
                    eq.getEquation().add(str.toString());
                    eq.getEquation().add(ArrOfStr[i]);
                    str.replace(0, str.length(), "");
                }
            }
            eq.getEquation().add(str.toString());
//          eq.getEquation().add(str);
            //System.out.print("last str : "+ str +"\n");
            System.out.println("Eq of Past mathod ----> "+ eq.getEquation());   

        }
        f.DisplayEq(eq.getEquation());
    }
```

> result : Eq of Past mathod ----> [violet+yellow]

thnk

Comment: is `eq` a StringBuilder?

Comment: No, my StringBuilder is called str. `eq` is an instance of my class equation which is an arrayList. That's why I am using `getEquation` because it returns me the arrayList.

Comment: ok what is the return type of `eq.getEquation()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your complex condition, the last `||` should probably also be an `&&`.

```
if(!ArrOfStr[i].equals("+") && !ArrOfStr[i].equals(".") && !ArrOfStr[i].equals("¤") &&
   !ArrOfStr[i].equals("!") && !ArrOfStr[i].equals("(") && !ArrOfStr[i].equals(")")) {
```

Or you could define a list of `operators` and then just check whether the current character is in that list:

```
List<String> operators = Arrays.asList("+", ".", "¤", "!", "(", ")");
if(! operators.contains(ArrOfStr[i])) {
```

Or just split by word-boundaries `\b`, possibly with some surrounding whitespace `\s*`

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s*\\b\\s*"));
```

Both ways you end up with `[violet, +, yellow]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the else block,

```
str.replace(0, str.length(), "");
```

will not 'reset' the str (but the return value). I believe you should use

```
str.setLength(0);
```

instead

Comment: It does not work... Now may arrList contains `str.setLength(0);`